# Samsung infinite scroll apps

Tags: samsung, app-drawer

I recently bought a Samsung smartphone which has its OneUI.
App drawer has horizontal scroll, but does not support infinite scroll. Is there any setting or an app I can install to get the infinite scroll?

To elaborate, in the app drawer, apps are arranged on different pages, with 4 x 5 apps per page. Suppose I'm on the last page, and I want to open an app in the first page, I'll have to scroll left all the way back to first page and then open the app. If infinite scroll is enabled, I can just scroll right and it would bring me to first page.

Comment: Try different home launcher apps. There are many with that feature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher)? It supports, if I understood your question correctly

Comment: Okay, will try that. Though I feel it's overkill to use a full-fledged launcher just for this small task... A small setting or an app would be better.